# How to import records which was made on local host using Google App Engine Launcher using Python to online App Engine datastore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I need to transfer all data in local datastore to online Google App Engine. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upload the data using a XML or CSV file. [Read this](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the bulkloader tool to download all data from your development datastore and upload it to your production datastore, as documented [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html#Downloading_and_Uploading_All_Data). You do not need to convert your data into CSV form first.